# IPCU in android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am looking for i phone configuration utility like tool in android. for configuration of profile. I know that configuring  wifi through code using wificonfiguration class is possible. As well as configuring wifi once the device boots by writing an intent receiver.

But I am looking for setting up wifi in the wifi settings code like in IPCU of iphone . Once setup need not write any configuration code using wificonfiguration class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any as of yet. One way you can implement this is to have your app on the device. Send messages to it using [C2DM](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-c2dm-messaging-server-push-for.html). The app configures WiFi and may be do more.

However, if you are looking for a ready-made solution, I'm not aware of any that exists - and if it does exist, it will certainly require an app on the device. There is currently no way to configure any settings on the Android without your own app.